# Change redirection after validation failed - laravel

Tags: validation, laravel-5.1

I am validating a user registration form

for EX: *`(Requests validation class)`*

```
class UserCreateAccountRequest extends Request
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|max:32'
        ];
    }

}
```

If the email is **already registered** I want to **redirect to the password reset** page.

How can i achieve this using request validation class without putting the validation in to the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the authorize function check whether the email already exists,

```
public function authorize()
{
    $email = Request::input('email');

    $result = User::where('email',$email)
            ->exists();

    if($result)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If this returns false, forbiddenResponse function will be fired, therefore you need to include that function and inside that you can redirect to the page you want. This function will only returns false if the email is already exist.

```
 public function forbiddenResponse()
{
    return redirect('password_reset');
}
```

That's all.For your reference following is the structure of the Request class,

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Response;

class FriendFormRequest extends FormRequest
{

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required',
        'email_address' => 'required|email'
    ];
}

public function authorize()
{
    // Only allow logged in users
    // return \Auth::check();
    // Allows all users in
    return true;
}

// OPTIONAL OVERRIDE
public function forbiddenResponse()
{
    // Optionally, send a custom response on authorize failure 
    // (default is to just redirect to initial page with errors)
    // 
    // Can return a response, a view, a redirect, or whatever else
    return Response::make('Permission denied foo!', 403);
}

// OPTIONAL OVERRIDE
public function response()
{
    // If you want to customize what happens on a failed validation,
    // override this method.
    // See what it does natively here: 
    // https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php
}

}
```